# Net Present Value Calculation for a Changing Variable

Tags: list-manipulation, summation, products

I have a list of 1000 lists, each comprising 100 pairs of numbers, with the first of these numbers running from 1 to 100, and the second being an output from an equation, dependent upon variable G.

Each list gives the results of an equation over 100 time periods (the 1-100 bit), for variable G in my equation taking each whole value between 1 and 1000 (hence 1000 lists).

I also have the following Net Present Value code:

```
NPV[d_,T_,r_,ex_]:= Sum[r[[t]]-ex[[t]]/Product[1+d[[j]],{j,1,t}],{t,1,T}]
```

I can make r equal to one of my 1000 lists, and one which ignores the first number in each pair (the 1-100 numbers). Thus r can be specified as a list of 100 numbers corresponding to an output over time for a given value of G. The NPV code discounts these outputs relative to their position in the list (the first output discounted by d, the second d^2 and so on.).
ex is also a function of G, so I can input the same value for G that corresponds to the list I have chosen for r, and turn this into a list of 100 numbers. These figures are likewise discounted as above. Thus if I make r equal to the list output when G = 200, I can plug 200 into my ex equation. I can therefore calculate the NPV for any specified value of variable G, when T = 100, and when I also pick a value for d.

However, what I am trying to do is plot the NPV results across all values of G between 1 and 1000, for T = 100, ex = 50000*G, and d = 0.05.

Any ideas how I make that work with my NPV code?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a little demo for some ideas.

```
lists = {
   {{1, 0.23}, {2, 0.32}, {3, 0.12}, {4, 0.11}, {5, 0.1}},
   {{1, 0.43}, {2, 0.52}, {3, 0.22}, {4, 0.21}, {5, 0.2}},
   {{1, 0.53}, {2, 0.62}, {3, 0.32}, {4, 0.31}, {5, 0.3}}};

NPV[d_, T_, r_, ex_] := Sum[r[[t]] - ex[[t]]/Product[1 + d[[j]], {j, 1, t}], {t, 1, T}]

calc[G_] := Module[{},
  r = Last /@ lists[[G]];
  T = Length[r];
  (* make up some values for ex and d as functions of G *)
  ex = 0.123 r/G;
  d = 0.456 r/G;
  NPV[d, T, r, ex]]

Labeled[ListLinePlot[Array[calc, Length[lists]],
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, Frame -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic],
 {Rotate["Net Present Value", 90 Degree], "G from 1 to 3"},
 {Left, Bottom}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Chris, that's getting me somewhere. However, I don't think I've fully understood the syntax. I want:
    ex = 50000*G and
    d = 0.05.
d is not dependent on G, and I don't think I have fully understood why r is needed in the ex and d equations you have given. When I input these equations for d and ex, it doesn't work. Is there any way to put these two equations in and get it to run smoothly?

Comment: @Steve You could add those details, as far as you have them, as an additional section to your question.  It would make clearer reading.

Comment: I have tried to amend it Chris. Thanks for your help.